# HTML table dynamically being populated by Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to dynamically populate an HTML table using JavaScript. For some reason, it's just not working.  I'm anticipating the code in the  area that is not enclosed in a function to automatically function upon loading the page, as I've read elsewhere.

When I load the page, I just get a blank white page, no table (not surprising, as it has no visible border), and no data populating it from the array...

```
<html>
    <script>
        var target = document.getElementById('dynPop');
        var i
        var j
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) 
        {  
            for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) 
            {  
                var tblr = document.createElement('tr');
                var tbld1 = document.createElement('td');
                var tbld2 = document.createElement('td');
                var tbld3 = document.createElement('td');
                var text1 = document.createTextNode(matrix[i][j])
                var text2 = document.createTextNode(matrix[i][j])
                var text3 = document.createTextNode(matrix[i][j])
                tbld1.appendChild(text1);
                tbld2.appendChild(text2);
                tbld3.appendChild(text3);
                tblr.appendChild(tbld1);
                tblr.appendChild(tbld2);
                tblr.appendChild(tbld3); 
                target.parentNode.insertBefore(tblr, target);
            }   
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr id="dynPop">
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason I forgot to add the array, but it still doesn't work with the array in the script section of the HTML...

Comment: var matrix [
  ["rose",1.20,3],
  ["tulip",1.40,4],
  ["orchid",1.50,5]
  ];

Comment: You can edit your questions. Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid. The `<script>` tag must be in either the `<head>` or the `<body>`, not as a direct child of the `<html>` element. In your case, try putting the `<script>` immediately before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Fair enough, I forgot to encapsulate the <script> tags in the <head> tags.

Comment: Added the <head> tag wrapping around the <script> tags.  No change.

Comment: That still won't be sufficient, because the script will execute before the browser has loaded the body into the DOM, so that element won't yet exist. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: Also moved script section to bottom, after </body>, no change there when I ran it, either.

Comment: Matt Ball is rightm look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ya4txKQJAhhCGQ6yapBm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It “works” once the suggested corrections are made, and the syntax error in your `matrix` variable definition is fixed (the missing `=` inserted) – but it is presumably still not what you *want*, because you are creating three `td` elements with the same text content for *each* value in your array.

What you actually want, is probably more like this:

```
var matrix = [
    ["rose", 1.20, 3],
    ["tulip", 1.40, 4],
    ["orchid", 1.50, 5]
];
var target = document.getElementById('dynPop');
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var text = document.createTextNode(matrix[i][j])
        td.appendChild(text);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(tr, target);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qLLW6/1/